# SOA versus Django ORM with multiple processes

Tags: python, django, sqlite, rest, orm

I have a django app which provides a rest api using Django-rest-framework. The API is used by clients as expected, but I also have another process(on the same node) that uses Django ORM to read the app's database, which is sqlite3.

Is it better architecture for the process to use the rest api to interact(only reads) with the app's database? Or is there a better, perhaps more efficient way than making a ton of HTTP requests from the same node?

The problem with the ORM approach(besides the hacky nature) is that occasionally reads fail and must be retried. Also, I want to write to the app's db which would probably causes more sqlite concurrency issues.

Comment: Why are you using sqlite in the first place if you expect concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your application is doing.  If your REST application reads a piece of data from SQLITE using the Django ORM and then the other app does a write you can run into some interesting race situations.  To prevent that it might make sense to have both these applications as django-app in a single Django project.